# Set of $n$ integers with all subsets a perfect power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am new to number theory, and I am stuck on this question:

Prove that for all integers $n$, there exists a set of $n$ integers, call it $S$, such that the sum of any subset of $S$ is a perfect power. Describe this set for $n=2017$.

I think that if I write it in the form:
$\{x,2x,3x,\cdots, nx\}$ where for $1 < k < (1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots+ n)$ $kx$ is a perfect power, I should be able to describe $x$ (and find it for $n=2017$), but I'm not sure how. 
I feel like I should be able to use the Chinese remainder theorem in some way, but I'm not sure how to apply the fact that values need to be perfect powers while thinking about factors remainders.

Please help!

Comment: Plese use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Here's a hint: if you choose $r \equiv 2 \pmod 6$, then $r$ is even and $r+1$ is divisible by $3$, so then both $x$ and $2x$ are perfect powers for $x = 2^r$.  Next, can you figure out how to choose $r$ to make $x$, $2x$ and $8x$ all perfect powers?  After that, try to choose both $r$ and $s$ so that $x$, $2x$, $3x$ are perfect powers for $x = 2^r 3^s$.  At that point you will be very close to a solution.

Comment: Does "the sum of any subset of S is a perfect power" mean that the number $\sum_{A\subset S}\sum_{a\in A}a$ is a perfect power?

Comment: @RobertZ No, it means that for every (non-empty) subset $A \subset S$, $\sum_{a\in A} a$ is a perfect power.  That's a lot of perfect powers so one must construct it carefully rather than guessing by trial and error :).

Comment: Any subset means singletons,too like $A=\{a\}$?  This means that all element must be perfect powers themselves

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, it may seem tricky but it is entirely doable.  Please read my earlier comment.  Critically, there is no requirement that each subset sum be the *same* power.

Comment: @Justin Sanders Could you please check your statement?
Do you need that "the sum of any subset of S is a perfect power" or "the sum of any subset of S is NOT a perfect power"?

Comment: @robert Z I meant *is*. I am thinking about what Erik Wong said, and I think I know better how to approach it.

Comment: Um... why isn't $7^1=7$ considered a perfect power?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \{1x, 2x, \dots , 2017x\}$ where $x$ is a a positive integer number to be determined.
Let $s_1,s_2,\dots, s_m$ be the sum of any non-empty subset of $\{1, 2, \dots , 2017\}$. It suffices to show that there is $x$ such that $x\cdot s_i$ is a perfect power for all $i=1,\dots,m$.

Let $p_1^{a_{1i}}\cdots p_{r}^{a_{ri}}$ be the prime factorization of $s_i$ (here $p_i$ denotes the $i$th prime) and let $p_1^{x_{1}}\cdots p_{r}^{x_{r}}$ be the prime factorization of $x$. Then $x\cdot s_i$ is a perfect power iff
$$g_i:=\gcd(a_{1i}+x_1,\dots,a_{ri}+x_r)\geq 2.$$
Now for each $j=1,\dots,r $, the system of congruences 
$$\begin{cases}
x_j\equiv -a_{j1} \pmod{p_1}\\
x_j\equiv -a_{j2} \pmod{p_2}\\
\dots\\
x_j\equiv -a_{jm} \pmod{p_m}\\
\end{cases}$$
has a solution by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. By taking $x_j$ in this way, it follows that $p_i$ divides $g_i$ which implies that $g_i\geq 2$ and we are done.

P.S. Note that asking for a set $S$ such that the sum of any subset of S is NOT a perfect power is much easier.
In fact, let $p$ be a prime with $p > \sum_{k=1}^{2017}k=2017\cdot 1009$
and let 
$$S = \{p, 2p, 3p, \dots , 2017p\}.$$
Then the sums of any non-empty subsets of $S$ is equal to $pm$, with 
$$m \leq \sum_{k=1}^{2017}k=2017\cdot 1009.$$
which implies that $m$ is not divisible by $p$. So we may conclude that the sum $mp$ is not a perfect power.

Comment: Just one question, since for all values of $i$ the prime factorization is different, how do we know that there exists a solution for x that applies to all $s$

Comment: $x$ depends on the exponents $x_j$ with $j=1,\dots,r$, each $x_j$ is a solution of a different system. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yup! Thanks, I misunderstood that final step.